# I want to know if I can get O(1) time complexity in counting the frequency of an array

Tags: data-structures

I have an  array with n elements, supposedly all of them are 1 initially. Then I have a function of "flip" in which it will negate my element at A[i] and takes O(1) of time. While function "count" which it will count the negated elements and take O(n) of time.

How is it possible for me to make my function flip become O(n) and function count O(1) using ADT?

Thanks

Comment: You need another field to record negative element count. But why does  function flip need to become O(n)?